# What is default username and password for JupyterHub?

Tags: jupyterhub

I have installed JupyterHub and ran it. When I opened its page, the following window appears:

[image]

What to enter there? Documentation is silent.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using docker image then after you run the container with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name jupyterhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub jupyterhub
```

bash into the running container:

```
docker exec -it jupyterhub bash
```

and then `adduser test` and follow the instructions. Once done then go to the browser enter:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

Put the credentials in. It should work as it worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

The username is "jovyan" and the password is "jupyter"

Comment: These seem to be the default credentials in JupyterHub in AWS EMR service.

Comment: not only there...got the same one on IBM Cloud as well ... will further investigate and update...

Answer (score 8):

You can login using your machine credentials.

Most probably you would be using sudospawner that is configured by default.

So any sudo user can login.

Comment: This answer worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Default spawner will use local operating system user credentials to spawn a Notebook or Lab process.

So `sudo adduser USER` then `sudo passwd USER` will create a user that can be used to log in.

Note that this user must have access to run the Notebook / Lab binary or it will log in but the spawning part would fail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must create a new user (especially if you are in a VM as I was).

In the VM (Qnap) I selected the "terminal" command and input adduser NewName

then got the password dialog. After it completed, I was able to login using that info.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials depends on the user running the command, it will be the same username and password as your linux user.

Answer (score 0):

By windows console, during the start use:

```
docker run -d -v ${PWD}:/home/jovyan/work -e GRANT_SUDO=yes --user root -p 8888:8888 jupyter/base-notebook
```

For linux:

```
docker run -d -v $PWD:/home/jovyan/work -e GRANT_SUDO=yes --user root -p 8888:8888 jupyter/base-notebook
```

So you can use `sudo` without password

Answer (score 0):

By windows console.

```
docker run -d -v %cd%:/home/jovyan/work -e GRANT_SUDO=yes --user root -p 8888:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
```

Using the docker exec command allows you to obtain a root prompt .

```
docker exec -it  youthful_albattani bash
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?